# App did not start error while running calabash tests

Tags: android, calabash

```
App did not start (RuntimeError)
 ./features/support/app_life_cycle_hooks.rb:5:in `Before'
```

throwing when I run

```
calabash-android run ../app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
```

I put

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

into my Manifest file, generated calabash tree via

```
calabash-android gen
```

and successfully ran the app on my emulator. Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the exception "App did not start" is not meaningful and can be raised in several situations. Sometimes I randomly have the same exception and if I run it again and it does not get raised.

Although it seems to me that you are doing it right, try the following tips:

- Uninstall your app
- Restart ADB:

  ```
  adb kill-server
  adb start-server
  adb wait-for-device
  ```
- Make sure your device is unlocked when you run calabash.